# Update 2 url params by input text and select

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to update 2 parameters in the URL of my service by input text and select

Url :  http://localhost/?population/?article=code&year=value

How can I set the code and value by input text for code and select for value in Angular 5

Thanks

Comment: Please improve your question by adding what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

```
getPopByCY(code: string, value : string): Observable<Article[]> {
    //set request params
    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set("article", code);
    params.set("year", value);
    //params.set("surname", surname); for more params
    this.options.search = params;  


    let url = "http://192.168.1.10:8080/RESTfulArticle/rest/article";
    console.log("url: ", url);

    return this.httpClient.get(url,this.options)
      .map((resp: Response) => resp.json() as Article[])
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(err) {
    console.log(err);
    return Observable.throw(err || 'Server error');
  }



}


article.component.ts

GetPbyCodeandYears(code : string , value : string) {


  this.countriesService.getPopByCY(code,value).subscribe(users => {
      this.pops = users as Population[];
      console.log(users);

    });
```

i want to append params to this link :   http://192.168.1.10:8080/RESTfulArticle/rest/article?country=code&year=value

Error : Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
    Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.